# Which hypothesis test should I use for this given situation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, python, t-test

Let's say I have lot of users who spend money on various items. Considering Item A:
For this item, I want to find whether there is a statistical difference in average spending in the month of October and September.

I am confused between ANOVA and Two Sample T-Test. I read somewhere that if you have one categorical variable and one continuous variable use T-test. Here, in this situation since I am only considering two months can I fit my situation in this case.

Whereas back of my mind, the month is a categorical variable with more than 2 categories. It was suggested to use the ANOVA test where you have one continuous variable and one categorical variable with more than 2 categories.

Please suggest the best hypothesis test which I should use in my scenario.

> Mean spending in October: 4.35 
> Std Dev of October: 1.95 
> Var of October: 3.81 
> Number of records october: 395

> Mean spending in Nov: 4.49 
> Std Dev of Nov: 1.96 
> Var of Nov: 3.85 
> Number of records Nov: 383

Comment: Can you match spending, customer-by-customer, to get paired data between Oct and Sept?

Comment: @BruceET yea essentially I can bt that will make this complicated. Wouldn't it?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, which attempts to convince you that the complication of looking at paired data could be worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I put your summary statistics into a recent release of Minitab
to do a 2-sample t test, with the result that there is no significant
difference between the two months.

```
Two-Sample T-Test and CI 

Sample    N  Mean  StDev  SE Mean
1       395  4.35   1.95    0.098
2       386  4.49   1.96     0.10

Difference = μ (1) - μ (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.140
95% upper bound for difference:  0.090
T-Test of difference = 0 (vs <): 
  T-Value = -1.00  P-Value = 0.159  DF = 778
```

I have two reservations. (1) If you were able to find something like
350 customers, so that we can see customer-by-customer how many
spent more in Nov then Oct, then we might have sufficient power
to find a significant difference---provided that one exists.
(2) Even with such large sample sizes, I would worry about using
a t test if expenditures are really far from normally
distributed. However, without normal data there are nonparametric
paired tests that might be appropriate.

---

Maybe I can illustrate the importance of pairing with some fake
data, using procedures in R:

**Paired test:** Shows highly significant difference.

```
x1 = rnorm(350, 4.35, 2)
x2 = x1 + rnorm(350, .12, .5)
t.test(x1, x2, pair=T)

        Paired t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -5.219, df = 349, p-value = 3.094e-07
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.18519286 -0.08381676
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
             -0.1345048
```

Here are summary of the paired differences and a plot of them. For my fake data, a convincing
majority of subjects increased spending in the second month. Your data may
not show such a significant result with paired data, but we will never
know without the 'complication' of looking at pairs.

```
d = x2 - x1
summary(d);  sd(d)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-1.3067 -0.1700  0.1231  0.1345  0.4720  1.6528 
[1] 0.4821507  # sample SD of differences

stripchart(d, pch="|")
  abline(v=0, col="green")
```

[image]

Furthermore, even if your expenditure data are not normal, you could use a (nonparametric) paired Wilcoxon (signed-rank) test to see if the differences are centered at $0$.

```
wilcox.test(d)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test 
        with continuity correction

data:  d
V = 39944, p-value = 1.098e-06
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location is not equal to 0
```

**Ignoring pairs** to do (inappropriate) two-sample test: nowhere near
a significant result.

```
t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -0.87948, df = 697.33, p-value = 0.3794
alternative hypothesis: 
  true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4347750  0.1657654
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 4.532307  4.666812
```

From parallel stripcharts we can see that purchases were more variable
in the second month, but without pairing, any difference in means gets
lost in the variability of the samples.

```
summary(x1);  sd(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-0.9581  3.0760  4.6222  4.5323  5.9310 10.2613 
[1] 1.991526
summary(x2);  sd(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -1.071   3.187   4.810   4.667   5.910  11.305 
[1] 2.054292

stripchart(list(x1,x2), ylim=c(.4,2.6), pch="|")
```

[image]

```
stripchart(list(x1,x2), ylim=c(.4,2.6), pch="|")
```